# How to extract url from my csv file in java

Tags: csv, url, extract

Thanks for your help in advance.

I have a CSV file, that has url of different web pages. I'd like to extract the url and below is the code that I have tried but , it returns repetitive result, without returning all the urls. Would you please give me some guidance? 
the CSV file is like: 
`[123,r5ttr, , , ,1224,http://www.example.com][244,rtyi, , ,3467,http://www.sample.com]` 
and so on.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bhttp.*?\\]");    
BufferedReader brd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("1234.CSV"));

while (brd.ready()) {
    String st = brd.readLine();
    Matcher m = p.matcher(st);              
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use the Regexp here. Just find the last comma index and the rest of the line is your url. It works faster.

The code will look something like this (sorry I don't have a java environment nearby so please think of it as a not debugged pseudocode :)

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("1234.CSV"))) {
    String csvLine;
    while ((csvLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        int urlStart = csvLine.length();
        while(true) if(csvLine.charAt(--urlStart) == ',') break;
        String theUrl = csvLine.substring(urlStart + 1, csvLine.length());
        System.out.println(theUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much.  I just didn't get urlPart in your pseudocode , what is its initial value?

Comment: sorry, I've corrected the code. There should be csvLine there.

Comment: I tried it, but it has error : String index out of range: 285. I should try again :)

Comment: I see you've corrected the csv file line example. You should just find the fifth comma index and the rest of the line is your url. See corrected code.

Comment: yes, when I opened it with Excel the format was like the first written sample, but in txt file the last value in each delimiter is the url .

Comment: I've just realized that it will be even more optimal to find the last comma. See corrected answer.

Comment: yes, I tried it, the problem is that it brings the only first url , although the file has around 300000, delimiter, when I put a loop such as while (brd.ready()) over your answer, it brings the meaningless and repetitive answers.

Comment: Oh yes, your're right. I've missed that part. You should use readLine to read each line and stop when it returns null. See updated sample.

Comment: yes, I did, by working on CSV file it returns String index out of range: -1 and if I read the same content in txt file , after bringing 1000 urls out of 300000, it brings the same error, I couldn't fix it.

Comment: yes, by changing the comma to tab, it is working. As the data about 175000 and sometimes to 300000, to have all of them, the result should be stored in the txt file. thanks a lot.

Comment: I only can check it as a useful one. since I don't have enough reputation I can't upvote it. sorry.

Comment: As soon as I got enough reputation I will do so.